# Implement Github API in Python

Tags: python, django, python-requests, github-api

I'm working on a project using Python(3.6) in which I need to implement GitHub API.
I have tried by using JSON apis as:

**from views.py:**

```
class GhNavigator(CreateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        term = request.GET.get('search_term')
        username = 'arycloud'
        token = 'API_TOKEN'
        login = requests.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=' + term, auth=(username, token))
        print(login)
        return render(request, 'navigator/template.html', {'login': login})
```

but it simply returns `status 200`, I want to get a list of repositories for `term` which is passed by the user.

How can I achieve that?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it print? What request do you make? You probably should call `login.json` to obtain the content packed into it.

Comment: when I prints `login.json` it returns `<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>`

Comment: `.json` is a function, so you should call it (i.e. `login.json()`).

Comment: does it includes commits also?

Comment: well that depends on how the API is used. I think you should inspect the GitHub API documentation. But a quick experiment myself, did not immediately yield commits.

Comment: you can check a sample answer in your browser https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `requests` library will return a `Response` object if you perform a `.get(..)`, `.post(..)` or anything like that. Since responses can be very huge (hundreds of lines), it does not print the content by default.

But the developers attached some convenient functions to it, for example to interpet the answer as a JSON object. A response object has a `.json()` function that aims to interpret the content as a JSON string, and returns its Vanilla Python counterpart.

So you can access the response (and render it the way you want), by calling `.json(..)` on it:

```
class GhNavigator(CreateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        term = request.GET.get('search_term')
        username = 'arycloud'
        token = 'API_TOKEN'
        response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=' + term, auth=(username, token))
        login = response.json()  # obtain the payload as JSON object
        print(login)
        return render(request, 'navigator/template.html', {'login': login})
```

Now of course it is up to you to interpret that object according to your specific "business logic", and render a page that you think contains the required information.